# Using jQuery to change text color after set time, and repeat infinitely

Tags: jquery

I found this answer:

[How can I change text after time using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630722/how-can-i-change-text-after-time-using-jquery)

Which basically does what I need. But instead of having it redirect to another page at the end, I want it to just keep cycling through the text messages infinitely. Obviously, I remove the IF section to stop the redirecting, but how do I make it repeatedly cycle through the text messages?

```
function nextMsg() {
    if (messages.length == 0) {
        // once there is no more message, do whatever you want
        alert("redirecting");
    } else {
        // change content of message, fade in, wait, fade out and
        // continue with next message
        $('#message').html(messages.pop()).fadeIn(500).delay(1000)
                                          .fadeOut(500, nextMsg);
    }
};

// list of messages to display var messages = [
//   "Hello!",
//   "This is a website!",
//   "You are now going to be redirected.",
//   "Are you ready?",
//   "You're now being redirected..."
// ].reverse();

// initially hide the message $('#message').hide();

// start animation nextMsg();
```

Comment: You can encase you code inside setInterval() and run it using a timespan

Answer (score 5):

Just make small changes in the basic code:

```
function nextMsg(i) {
    if (messages.length == i) {
        i = 0;
    }

    $('#message').html(messages[i])
                 .fadeIn(500)
                 .delay(1000)
                 .fadeOut(500, function() {
                     nextMsg(i + 1);
                 });
};

nextMsg(0);​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8wqv2/

Comment: I updated your fiddle so that now it's shorter: http://jsfiddle.net/8wqv2/1/ I dropped the whole `if` statement and called `nextMsg(++i%messages.length)` instead.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing there! That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks all! That's perfect, and even more important, I follow the logic. I'm learning!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aq5wx/) work?