# How to change text after time using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I found this code on stackoverflow [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630722/how-can-i-change-text-after-time-using-jquery) , but it's not working for me...

I can see this only:

```
Hello world!
Here is a message:
```

,but I don't see the messages that should be changing after time...

I copy/paste the entire code from my file index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">


</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function nextMsg() {
    if (messages.length == 0) {
        alert("redirecting");
    } else {
        $('#message').html(messages.pop()).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500,     nextMsg);
    }
};

var messages = [
    "Hello!",
    "This is a website!",
        "You are now going to be redirected.",
    "Are you ready?",
    "You're now being redirected..."
].reverse();

$('#message').hide();
nextMsg();
</script>

<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>Here is a message: <span id="message"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Wrap all into document.ready()

Comment: ^ that -> http://jsfiddle.net/fbd02x33/

Comment: Take a look in debug console , the same code is here http://jsfiddle.net/5s8y3/1/ and works great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the order dont execute javascript at the beginning of your code always at the end and/or use document ready to be sure dom is loaded before executing js

```html
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <p>Here is a message: <span id="message"></span></p>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
function nextMsg() {
    if (messages.length == 0) {
        alert("redirecting");
    } else {
        $('#message').html(messages.pop()).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500,nextMsg);
    }
};


var messages = [
    "Hello!",
    "This is a website!",
        "You are now going to be redirected.",
    "Are you ready?",
    "You're now being redirected..."
].reverse();

$('#message').hide();
nextMsg();
});
</script>
```