# change text after time using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

There are already some answers on this site but couldn't figure out what I need.

Using the answer accepted as good given here: [How can I change text after time using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630722/how-can-i-change-text-after-time-using-jquery)

But, instead of having an alert, I'd like to make it reload to its first message (adding full codes for clarity:

```js
function nextMsg() {
    if (messages.length == 0) {
        // once there is no more message, I don't know how to start the script over (loop it)
    } else {
        $('#message').html(messages.pop()).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, nextMsg);
    }
};

var messages = [
    "Hello!",
    "This is a website!",
    "You are now going to be redirected.",
    "Are you ready?",
    "You're now being redirected..."
].reverse();

$('#message').hide();
nextMsg();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>Here is a message: <span id="message"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

On another answer I had also find something similar, but I couldn't add fade in and fade out:

```js
        var example = ['<a href="#"> link1</a>', '<a href="#"> link2</a>'];

        textSequence(0);
        function textSequence(i) {

            if (example.length > i) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById("sequence").innerHTML = example[i];
                    textSequence(++i);
                }, 5000); //  milliseconds

            } else if (example.length == i) { // Loop
                textSequence(0);
            }

        }
```

```html
<div id="sequence"></div>
```

This may seem like a simple answer, but while I understand html and css to an extent, jscript is  still out of my reach, so an answer with some clarity onto it would be great.

Thanks to anyone that will answer.

Comment: do you just want to loop over an array of text?

Comment: No I'd like for it to loop to the first text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pop` in the first example is actively removing elements from your `messages` array - so you can't "start the script over" because you have basically destroyed your data.

Think of `pop` as taking an items out of a bag one at a time and throwing them away - obviously when there are no items left in the bag - you can't then start again trying to get items out of the bag - because there is nothing left in the bag.

```js
function nextMsg(index) {
if (messages.length === index) {
    nextMsg(0);
} else {
    $('#message').html(messages[index])
        .fadeIn(500)
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeOut(500, () => nextMsg(index + 1));
}
};

var messages = [
'<a href="#"> link1</a>',
'<a href="#"> link2</a>',
'<a href="#"> link3</a>',
'<a href="#"> link4</a>'
];

$('#message').hide();

nextMsg(0);
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
  <p>Here is a message: <span id="message"></span></p>
   </body>
```

As you can see there is no need to `copy` or duplicate the data - nor is there any need to `reverse` the messages.

Simply use the message index to keep track of which message to display and loop the index.

Comment: I tried your option, and while it works, I can't add a link. if I go and add a link, due to variables starting with " it causes problems. Example: "<a href="#">link</a>
in this case, he recognizes only "<a href=" while the rest is thought as a comment(I suppose?)

Comment: @MorganPubblicita Just use single quotes for your links '<a href="#">link</a>' - see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You are using pop to empty the original list. You need to keep the original list in place in order to start over:

```js
function nextMsg() {
    if (messages.length == 0) {
      messages = copy(originalMessages);
      nextMsg();
    } else {
        $('#message').html(messages.pop()).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, nextMsg);
    }
};

var originalMessages = [
    "Hello!",
    "This is a website!",
    "You are now going to be redirected.",
    "Are you ready?",
    "You're now being redirected..."
].reverse()

var messages = copy(originalMessages);

function copy(x){
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
}

$('#message').hide();
nextMsg();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>Here is a message: <span id="message"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```js
var example = ['<a href="#"> link1</a>', '<a href="#"> link2</a>'];

textSequence(0);
function textSequence(i) {
  $('#sequence').html(example[i])
  $('#sequence').fadeIn(500)
  if (example.length > i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          $('#sequence').fadeOut(500);
          setTimeout(function() {
            textSequence(++i);
          },600);
      }, 5000);

  } else if (example.length == i) { // Loop
      textSequence(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='sequence'></div>
```